# Where can I find a good tutorial or book for various MySQL performance guidelines?

Tags: mysql, database-design

Can anyone refer me a good book or a small tutorial for various use cases for database design on MySQL for high load test/high availability scenarios.

It should include the following:

1. What are the various scenarios/solutions for high availability?
2. What are the various scenarios for high load and how to cater them
   based on reliability, response time, throughput etc.

I am particularly interested if someone knows of a practical experience book for both of these cases.

Answer (score 3):

I read these:

1. [MySQL High Availability](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596807290.do)
2. [High Performance MySQL](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596101718.do)

They are good enough.

Answer (score 2):

[High Performance MySQL, 3rd edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1449314287), is *by far* the best book out there on performance and other issues. I have a bookshelf of 20+ MySQL books, some of which deal with performance. None are as clear, insightful or full as this book.

You should also note the 3rd edition has just been published a few months ago, and it is very up-to-date with current MySQL development.

Among other issues, it speaks of:

- Schema design
- Indexing
- Performance tuning
- High availability
- MySQL on the cloud
- Benchmarking
- Profiling

And lots more. Is is very practical and is based on the experience of its authors as employees/founders of Percona, a MySQL consulting company, as consultants and developers of MySQL and popular MySQL tools.

The [MySQL High Availability](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596807290.do) book suggested in another answer, is centralized around MySQL replication. It is a good book, but does not provide with a thorough review & comparison of available HA solutions. It is authored by developers of Replication within Oracle/MySQL and covers replication in great depth.

There's a [High Availability MySQL Cookbook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1847199941), which provides a good overview of available HA solutions (already out-of-date as of Galera's appearance, and the demise of other solutions). I think it shows the basics well, so you can get the general picture.